# How do I eval two commands?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

If I run this:

```
echo "echo 'a'; echo 'b'"
```

It produces a string which I can then run, and it works - echoes `a\nb\n`.

However, this does not work:

```
$(echo "echo 'a'; echo 'b'")
```

Why not? It doesn't work for any command, not just echo. How do I execute a string containing two or more commands?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `eval $(echo "echo 'a'; echo 'b'")` works without problems. It is in general not a good idea to talk about problems instead of giving the exact error message(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `$(echo "echo 'a'; echo 'b'")`, the shell sees a command substitution. And that's it. So that's going to be a simple command whose arguments are the resulting of the split+glob operator upon the expansion of the command substitution.

The shell will take the output of the `echo "echo 'a'; echo 'b'"` command, in this case `echo 'a'; echo 'b'\n`, remove the trailing newline characters so that becomes `echo 'a'; echo 'b'`, split that according the value of the `$IFS` variable.

If `$IFS` has not been changed from its default, that will be 4 words: `echo`, `'a';`, `echo` and `'b'`. Each of those words will be subject to globbing. Here, none contain globbing characters, so those words will stay as they are.

So we've got 4 arguments to run a simple command. The first argument will be used to derive the command to run. `echo` is built-in most shells. So the shell will call its `echo` builtin with those 4 arguments.

`echo` ignores its first (0th) argument and outputs the other ones separated by space characters and terminated by a newline character. Some `echo` implementations expand backslash escape sequences, but there's none here. So `echo` will output:

```
'a'; echo 'b'\n
```

If you want to eval it, that is if you want to have that string interpreted as shell code, use `eval`:

```
eval "echo 'a'; echo 'b'"
```

That's also recognised as a simple command. Because of the quotes, the shell sees two "words": `eval` and `echo 'a'; echo 'b'`. Again, those will make up the arguments to the command that is derived from the first.

Here the command is the shell's `eval` builtin command. Again, `eval` ignores its first agument. What it does is concatenate its other arguments (here there's only one) with spaces and interpret the resulting string as shell code. When interpreting

```
echo 'a'; echo 'b'
```

The shell sees an unquoted `;` which delimits commands. The first one is treated as a simple command which ends up calling `echo` with two arguments... etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if eval "( service networking restart &> /dev/null   &&   ping -c3 google.com &> /dev/null )"; then      
   echo "service is running"                              
else  
   echo "service is not running"    
fi
```

Comment: You don't seem to actually need the `eval` in your example.